# Should frequently accessed tables containing large blobs with one-to-one relationships be normalized and columns split into two tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, blob

I have a frequently accessed table containing 3 columns of blobs, and 4 columns of extra data that is not used in the query, but just sent as result to PHP. There are 6 small columns (big int, small int, tiny int, medium int, medium int, medium int) that are used in the queries in the WHERE/ORDER BY/GROUP BY.

The server has very low memory, around 1GBs, and so the cache is not enough to improve the performance one on the large table. I've indexed the last 6 small columns, but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Would it be a good solution to split this large table into two?
One table containing the last 6 columns, and the other containing the blobs and extra data, and link it to the previous table with a foreign key that has a one to one relationship?
I'll then run the queries on the small table, and join the little number of rows remaining after filtering to the table with the blobs and extra data to return them to PHP.

Please note, I've already done this, and I managed to decrease the query time from 1.2-1.4 seconds to 0.1-0.2 seconds. However I'm not sure if the solution I've tried is considered good practice, or is even advisable at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have implemented is sometimes called "vertical partitioning".  If you take it to the extreme, then it is the basis for columnar databases, such as Vertica.

As you have observed, such partitioning can dramatically increase query performance.  One reason is that less data needs to be read for processing a row of data.

The downside is for updates, inserts, and deletes.  With all the data in a single row, these operations are basically atomic -- that is, the operation only affects one row in a data page.  (This is not strictly true with blobs, because these are split among multiple pages.)

When you split the data among multiple tables, then you need to coordinate these operations among the tables, so you don't end up with "partial" rows of data.

For a database being used with bulk inserts and lots of querying, this is not a particularly important consideration.  Your splitting of separate columns of the data into separate tables is a reasonable approach for improving performance.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Yes, as you've said, the insert/updates and deletes are quite a bit of pain to handle. That and my lack of experience and hesitating if this is a viable solution is the reason why I haven't gone through fully with this. But considering the performance hit, it seems to be worth it, especially since as you say, I'm not doing some really horrible thing that is on the "never do" list of DBAs.